# Spin up custom ETH based blockchain: just changing the genesis and toml?

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, genesis, forks

If I wanted, lets say, to power on a clone of BSC (just to have a PoA version of the thing), would it be enough to follow the full node setup guide from Binance and just edit the config.toml and the genesis.json?

If I do this on 4 servers providing the mutual IP address as StaticNodes or BootstrapNodes, will this just create a new chain identical to BSC with my 4 nodes and the chainID I choose?

If not, what else should i do?